# Graph visual layout

Tags: algorithm, layout, graph, tree

I'm trying to draw graphs (trees), and I looking for a algorithms to layout the graph. Is there a library to do that in c/c++/objective-c? Otherwise, can somebody point to a good resource for that, preferably available online?

The nodes might be of varying sizes.

Answer (score 8):

The [igraph](http://igraph.sourceforge.net) library has quite a few [layout algorithms](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/ch14s01.html) for graphs, although you might also find it "overly complex". It's written in C, so you can embed it in C, C++ or Objective C apps.

Specifically, for tree drawing, I would use the [Reingold-Tilford layout algorithm](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/html/igraph_layout_reingold_tilford.html). Alternatively, you can go for the Sugiyama layout (see Chapter 5 in [this PDF](http://userweb.port.ac.uk/~addist/Layout.pdf)), but I am not aware of any open source C/C++ implementation for that, so you have to roll your own. Incidentally, a Sugiyama-style layout is used by GraphViz when it draws layered graphs.

*Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of igraph.*

Comment: +1 - Nice job.  And thank you for the disclaimer - that kind of honesty should be celebrated here.

Comment: igraph is under the  GNU GPL and is thus copyleft.

Comment: Can graph be compiled for iOS in Xcode?

Comment: GOBLIN does Sugiyama layout but it's LGPL. http://goblin2.sourceforge.net/

Comment: there's a Sugiyama layout implementation in Java as part of the modsl system, Apache licensed. i was able to convert it reasonably easily to a mixed Objective-C/Objective-C++ implementation based on the digraph library. source is here: https://github.com/damiannz/digraph

Answer (score 2):

AT&T's Graphviz lays out graphs automatically and does a very good job.  Why do you think it's complex?  All you have to do is create an input file of the appropriate type.  I can't imaging something simpler.

I'd advise you to give it another look - you'll find it's worth it.  I'll be surprised if there's a tool that much easier - all you have to do is give the data.

Comment: I'm dealing with a dynamic view on the data. Writing down to a file every time the data changes sounds quite inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [GDToolkit](http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~gdt/) (Graph Drawing Toolkit)

But it doesn't have a free licence, as I see just now :(